# Twitter Bootstrap - what tag should I use to color some text?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have some text and I want to color a certain word to make it stand out.
for instance:

```
This is my text, <span class="red">this</span> should be red.
```

Is using the span tag correct? Or is there a different convention,

Bonus: What about bold and italic?

Comment: `<strong>` & `<em>` for bold and italic, or you could do `<span style="font-weight: bold;"></span>` & `<span style="text-decoration: underline;"></span>`

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you've posted a question, it belongs to the Stack Overflow community at large (under the CC-by-SA license). If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323395/584192)?

Answer (score 2):

Span is the right way to do it. Doing it with the class is also a good way forward. You need to ask yourself however, if this is the way you will be consistently emphasizing content on your page.

If so you may consider overriding `<em>` tag for bootstrap. Default behavior is making text italic.

I'm not going in details how to customize Bootstrap itself. Overriding the default style is simple enough. Simply, in your custom css add:

```
em { 
  color: red; 
  font-style: normal; 
}
```

This code `font-style: normal;` changes italic to normal.

In your html use `em`

To answer the other part of your question: 
italic: `<em></em>` bold:`<strong></strong>`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Twitter Bootstrap, you can use:

    `<span class="active">...</span>
    <span class="success">...</span>
    <span class="warning">...</span>
    <span class="danger">...</span>`

see Bootstrap doc: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-contextual-classes